# android facebook authorization(SDK 3.0) FB prompts login twice

Tags: android, facebook

I have a mobile app (for android) with Facebook login (FB SDK 3.0). It works fine ,and posts on FB through the native FB app but when Facebook app is not installed on phone it prompts for twice login the it posts on FB wall. I searched a lot on why it prompts for twice login, but didnt found any helping blog or post. Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem as you too. I wanted to request a read permission then request a publish stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I've been able to tell from my current development, (and obviously depending on your code), the first login is the general login and the second is asking for permissions though it doesn't present the login window as such.

I saw once that it asked for permissions but I'm still not able to duplicate this.

Comment: I've finally solved my problem and found a difference between Authorizing my app and then requesting new permissions straight after login (at which point it'd ask to log in with user/pass a second time if app isn't installed (what i though may be your issue)) as opposed to opening a request for publish directly, due to vague documentation and tutorials i was lead to believe it wasn't possible to log in with publish permissions for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The annswer checked isnt great. Before the setUserInfoChangedCallback is called on the login button set your permissions list for the button:

```
loginButton.setPublishPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
.....
}
```